# Edit existing 'if' condition to add a class to a div and display / hide divs

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I am using a template which has an 'if' argument to alter the output of a div containing an image field. I need to add my own condition (within comments) to it. Currently the output is creating the image twice (see attached screenshot).

```
<!-- added for publication image formatting -->
  {% if content.field_download_resource|render %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass('pub-img') }}> {{ content.field_image }}
  {% endif %}
  </div>
<!-- end add for publication image formatting -->

<div class="post-thumbnail post-{{ post_format }}">
  {% if post_format == 'video' or post_format == 'audio' and gva_iframe %}
    {{ gva_iframe|raw }}
  {% elseif post_format == 'gallery' and content.field_post_gallery %}
    {{ content.field_post_gallery }}
  {% else %}
    {{ content.field_image }}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

The first 'if' argument confirms if there is a value for the field download_resource, and if there is a value, it adds the class '.pub-img' to the div containing the output of field_image. The second 'if' argument acts on the same div but displays the content of different fields, **OR** the same field_image with a different class applied to it, depending on different conditions. Right now my page output is displaying **BOTH** images, as below:

[image]

I don't want that to happen. What I need to do is **ONLY** display the output of the first 'if' argument in the div (and remove the display of the larger image) if there is a value for the field_download_resource, **OR ELSE** display **ONLY** the larger image and not the smaller image (output of the first 'if' argument).

I have tried various methods to combine the two 'if' arguments into one, but nothing seems to work. I get the "unexpected error" message. I have reached the limit of my knowledge of drupl 8 Twig theming, and am now appealing to the experts to lend a hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a class to the image tag in field.html.twig?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263713/how-to-add-a-class-to-the-image-tag-in-field-html-twig)

Comment: No, I need to add/merge my (already working) condition to an existing 'if' loop in this template and make it all work. Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the correct code, which I figured out after a lot of trial and error. Posting it here so that it helps someone else in the same predicament.

```
<!-- added for publication image formatting -->
  {% if content.field_download_resource|render %}
  <div class="pub-img"> {{ content.field_image }} </div>
<!-- end add for publication image formatting -->

{% elseif content.field_download_resource|render is empty %}

<div class="post-thumbnail post-{{ post_format }}">
  {% if post_format == 'video' or post_format == 'audio' and gva_iframe %}
    {{ gva_iframe|raw }}
  {% elseif post_format == 'gallery' and content.field_post_gallery %}
    {{ content.field_post_gallery }}
  {% else %}
    {{ content.field_image }}
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% endif %}
```

Thanks...