# Add class to {{ link }} twig attribute

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to apply a button class to the {{ link }} attribute in code below.

```
<span{{attributes}}><a class="usa-button"{{ link }}</span>
```

It displays correctly however the markup is not correct. I see an extra `<a=""` tag.

```
<a class="usa-button" <a="" href="http://sites.localhost/sites/default/files/Image%20styles%20for%20grid%20view_3.docx" type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; length=14535">Image styles for grid view_3.docx</a>
```

Any ideas on how to apply class cleanly?

Comment: Since you're in Twig, I think what you're looking for is this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/260232/79805. If not Twig, the other answers should work. In twig, you'd be looking for `attributes.addClass()`, but you cannot apply it with the above template. The reason you see two `<a>` tags is that `{{ link }}` contains an `<a>` tag itself. If you want to apply the class via Twig with `addClass()` you will need a new template for your link field.

Answer (score 4):

This is how to do it:

```
{{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class': ['text-blue500', 'text-3xl'] }) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your easiest approach would be to modify the field template and add a wrapping span with classes you need.

**field--field-name.html.twig**:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <span{{ item.attributes.addClass('my-class') }}>{{ item.content }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

or replace span and content with to add class directly to `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="{{ item.content['#url']}}" class="my-class">{{ item.content['#title'] }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rebuild the link(a href tag) with relevant attributes you require. You can add class, id, download or target blank as well. Refer definition below -

```
function THEME_preprocess_file_link(&$variables)
{

  $file = $variables['file'];
  $link_text = '';
  $options = array();
  $file_entity = $file instanceof File ? $file : File::load($file->fid);
  $url = file_create_url($file_entity
    ->getFileUri());
   // Use the description as the link text if available.
  if (empty($variables['description'])) {
    $link_text = $file_entity
      ->getFilename();
  }
  else {
    $link_text = $variables['description'];
    $options['attributes']['title'] = $file_entity
      ->getFilename();
  }

  $variables['attributes']->addClass(array('cta'));//Adding class to span
  $options['attributes']['download'] = TRUE;//Adding attribute to l
  $options['attributes']['target'] = array('_blank');//Adding attribute to l
  $variables['link'] = \Drupal::l($link_text, Url::fromUri($url, $options));

}
```

Comment: The question asks about a link field. Your answer is for a link to a file.